# How to Find a text in page and then add hyperlink to it using JS?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hyperlink

I am developing a Wordpress website and installed a theme. Some of the elements don't have the option to add hyperlinks to it, so I am trying to add hyperlinks or make the blocks clickable using JS.

I want to add hyperlinks to those li elements and theme currently doesn't support it.

My Logic:

1. Search for the text in li once page loads.
2. Add Hyperlink to it if text is found.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <ul class="cyber-item">
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> abcd
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> efgh
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> Content Delivery Network
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> 24/7 Hours services
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to tackle this. If you're using jquery already you might want to take a look at the documentation for the `.wrap()` function: https://api.jquery.com/wrap/

If you're not using jquery, it's simple enough to do with plain js. You will first need to select all the `<li>` elements and then loop through them and replace the contents with your `<a>` tags one by one. You can do this by modifying the element's `innerHTML` property.

I will say this seems like a strange issue. There must be a way for you to add links to your content without resorting to this method. And you'll still need to figure some other problems out - how will you know where each link should go, for instance?

Anyway, here is a snippet so you can see the principle behind what you asked:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li')
items.forEach((item) => {
  const children = item.innerHTML
  item.innerHTML='<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">' + children + '</a>'
})
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <ul class="cyber-item">
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> abcd
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> efgh
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> Content Delivery Network
    </li>
    <li>
      <i class="bx bx-check"></i> 24/7 Hours services
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The following code worked but problem is now the css is broken also how to add different links to li elements , jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".manual-content ul li").wrap("<a href=\"security\"></a>");
});